# Turning object column into JSON column

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have an object column in a dataframe with this data structure:

```
{"sku":"AHG5289"}, {"sku":"MCPV443"}, {"sku":"KBP2646"}, {"sku":"KCB2677"}, {"sku":"OR6344"}, {"sku":"WFM5449"}, {"sku":"TCM3322"}, {"sku":"ADE5357"}, {"sku":"MCP6412"}
```

And I'm hoping to convert it so that it becomes a proper JSON formatted column with this structure:

```
[{"sku":"AHG5289"}, {"sku":"MCPV443"}, {"sku":"KBP2646"}, {"sku":"KCB2677"}, {"sku":"OR6344"}, {"sku":"WFM5449"}, {"sku":"TCM3322"}, {"sku":"ADE5357"}, {"sku":"MCP6412"}]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Edit: I have tried `to_json(orient="records")` but it adds a bunch of weird backslashes and quotations marks such that it looks like this:

```
["{\"sku\":\"AHG5289\"}, ..."]
```

Comment: What is the type of the column? `print(type(df['col'].iloc[0]))`

Comment: `<class 'str'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add `[` and `]` to the start and end of each row in the column, and use `json.loads` for each row:

```py
import json
df['col'] = ('[' + df['col'] + ']').apply(json.loads)
```

Comment: I get: 

`[{'sku': 'AHG5289'}, {'sku': 'MCPV443'},...]`

Which is really close but doesn't proper JSON take double quotes?

Comment: When they're single quotes, it's because the data is actual Python dicts inside the dataframe. If you want it as stringified JSON, just add `.apply(json.dumps)` to the end of the code above.

Comment: Amazing! I sure learned something today. Thank you :-)